# What happens in axum when a header is missing for a handler capturing a typed header?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-axum

axum allows me to capture http headers in a handler with the `TypedHeader` struct. For example:

```rust
async fn handler(TypedHeader(if_none_match): TypedHeader<IfNoneMatch>) -> String {
    let etag = "foo".parse::<ETag>().unwrap();
    if if_none_match.precondition_passes(&etag) {
        String::from("success")
    } else {
        String::from("failure")
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering what happens if I get a request where the `If-None-Match` header is missing. With some debugging, I found out that the handler will still be called and the precondition will pass. However, I'm wondering what the instance of `IfNoneMatch` is now which I'm receiving? How is axum setting this instance and how can I determine whether the header was originally missing? I used the `If-None-Match` http header as an example here, but I would be interested in a general answer.

Comment: [`TypedHeader`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/src/axum/typed_header.rs.html#54) forwards to [`header::Header::decode`](https://docs.rs/headers/latest/headers/trait.Header.html), which takes a (potentially empty) iterator of header values. You can travel up the code from there.

Comment: I see that `TypedHeader::from_request_parts` should return a `TypedHeaderRejectionReason::Missing`. However, I can't figure out how I can capture this in my handler.